# How can i Make This Type SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a table in data base which has column  MonthNo ,Year ,MonthValue ,AvgYTD and it has values in

```
 1 ROW... 1 , 2010 , 2.3 , 4.0  AND

 2 ROW...  2, 2010, 3.3 ,5.0 AND

 3 ROW.. 3, 2010, 3.3, 7.9
```

AND I want output in my SSRS.....

WHEN I SELECT MONTH MARCH USING PARAMETER THEN OUTPUT WILL BE....A TABLE AND IT HAS COLUMN

```
JAN  ,  FEB , MARCH , AVGYTD   and  values in row are .. 

 2.3  ,3.3, 4.3, 7.9
```

**Updates**

i am using sql server 2005 and 7.9 is th AvgYTD Value comes from table for selected month march....

i want ...if i select month march then output will be show month value of jan,feb and march and AvgYTD value for only selected month..

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use a matrix, and if SQL 2005, use the InScope function to be able to tell if you're in the SubTotal column. In SQL 2008 you can just put a column in there for the appropriate YTD value.

Edit, to explain it more thoroughly:

Put a Matrix in the report. Use a column group on Year, MonthNo. By default that group will be called matrix1_ColumnGroup1 (or something like that - go to Edit Group to set it to something better). Put a row group on whatever causes a second row to appear.

In the Cell part of the Matrix, use an expression like:

```
=IIF(InScope("matrix1_ColumnGroup1"), First(Fields!MonthValue.Value), Last(Fields!AvgYTD.Value))
```

Comment: I dont know how to use Matrix please tell me complete solution i m in trouble from two days

Comment: Start by telling me which version of ssrs you're using, and where 7.9 comes from.

Comment: hi rob,
 

i am using sql server 2005 and 7.9 is th AvgYTD Value comes from table for selected month march....

i want ...if i select month march then output will be show month value of jan,feb and march and AvgYTD value for only selected month..

thanks,